# Trying to figure out how to power this heart rate sensor circuit

Tags: power, msp430

[image: Circuit Schematic]
I'm using an MSP430 as my mcu, and a nokia 5110 lcd display. Both these devices work off of 3.3V. The LM324 opamps work with a minimum of 3V, so using 2xAA batteries will be cutting it close. I could use a 9V battery for the heart rate circuit portion, and use a 3.3V regulator for the msp430 and LCD, but regulating 9V->3.3V will waste a lot of energy. What is the best way I can go about this? I am open to using a different op-amp.

Comment: I'd look into a different opamp.  Say, maybe an MCP604 (or an MCP601 and an MCP602) since you need three opamps.

Comment: What are your maximum voltages as well?  9V batteries are kind of not great.  Going to a superior or common battery type like lithium ion 18650s can be well worth losing 20% of your power in a voltage conversion (could be as low as 5% for that matter).  You could also consider NiMHx3 depending on your voltage limit and linear regulators if you only need to drop a few hundred mV, depending on current.

Comment: If you can afford the space it will take up I'd consider a single 18650 with a decent buck/boost or a 2x18650 battery pack with a buck converter.

Comment: You could also consider a single protected 18650.  Start at 3.8V and just shut down when voltage is too low.  Lithium ion batteries are very friendly to not being completely discharged.